# Everytime I try to run my code I get this error message: SyntaxError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 5: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, visual-studio

Everytime I try to run my code I get this error message: SyntaxError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 5: invalid continuation byte

I can't even begin to solve the problem cause I just started learning Python, and I get this error message every time I try to run my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Program Files\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "D:\Program Files\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)

File"d:\programfiles\visualstudio\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy_*main*_.py", line 39, in 
cli.main()

File "d:\program files\visual studio\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
run()

File "d:\program files\visual studio\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
runpy.run_path(target, run_name="**main**")

File "d:\program files\visual studio\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 320, in run_path
code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "d:\program files\visual studio\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 294, in _get_code_from_file
code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "C:\Users\detri\source\repos\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1\PythonApplication1.py", line 1
print("Eredm�ny:", 3*5)
^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 5: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Did you save your file with an UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Where can I change the encoding?

Comment: That depends on your editor/IDE.